# Place a background image over an image

Tags: html, css

Im trying to put a background image over an image.

Basically its to show if a 'user' has approved or denied something.

I want if approved to display a green tick over the users display image.

I tried to create it but what i have does not work.

This is what i have so far:

Html

```
<img class="small-profile-img accepted" src="http://www.image.com/image.gif" alt="">
```

CSS

```
.small-profile-img{
    width:30px;
    display:inline;
    border:2px solid #000000;
}

.accepted{
    background-image:url("tick.png") !important;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:right bottom;
    z-index:100;
    background-size:18px;
}
```

See jsfiddle for working example.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vpgjr/1/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution would be is to use wrapper with `after` pseudo element for `accepted` class:

```
.accepted:after {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    height: 18px;
    width: 18px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    background-image:url("http://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/checkout-icons/32x32/tick.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: right bottom;
    z-index: 100;
    background-size: 18px;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="small-profile-img accepted">
    <img src="http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-KLcHPORC4do/TbJCkjjkiBI/AAAAAAAAACw/zDnMSWC_R0M/s1600/facebook-no-image1.gif" alt="">
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vpgjr/7/

Comment: Best solution for this issue.

Answer (score 2):

Background images go *behind* foreground content. An `<img>` is foreground content.

The only way you could see the background image would be if the foreground image had translucent pixels over the background image.

The tick appears to be content (rather than decoration) though, so it should probably be represented as an `<img>` anyway.

```
<div class="image-container">
    <img class="small-profile-img"
         src="http://www.image.com/image.gif" 
         alt="">
    <img class="approved"
         src="tick.png"
         alt="Approved">
</div>

.image-container { 
    position: relative;
}

.image-container .small-profile-img {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;
}

.image-container .approved {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 3;
    top: 50px;
    left: 50px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you use position:absolute

HMTL

```
<div class="wrap">
<img src="http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-KLcHPORC4do/TbJCkjjkiBI/AAAAAAAAACw/zDnMSWC_R0M/s1600/facebook-no-image1.gif" alt="">
    <div class="inner"> <img src="http://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/checkout-icons/32x32/tick.png" width="18"/></div>
    </div>
```

CSS

```
.wrap{
    position:relative;
    background:red;
    height:auto; width:30px;
    font-size:0
}
.wrap > img{
        width:30px;
        display:inline;
    }
.inner{
        position:absolute; 
        top:30%; 
        left:50%;
        margin:-5px 0 0 -9px
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/vpgjr/4/)**

Answer (score 0):

set

```
position:absolute
```

Then set left,top (bottom,right if needed) property.

Answer (score 0):

yea, i'd go the other way around.
change the class of the img when it's accepted.

HTML:

```
<div class='holder'>
    <img  class='unaccepted' src="http://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/checkout-icons/32x32/tick.png" alt="">    
</div>
```

CSS:

```
    .small-profile-img{
        width:30px;
        display:inline;
        border:2px solid #000000;
    }
.holder{
    width:40px;
    height:30px;
    background-image:url("http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-KLcHPORC4do/TbJCkjjkiBI/AAAAAAAAACw/zDnMSWC_R0M/s1600/facebook-no-image1.gif");
    background-size: 100%, 100%;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:center;
    text-align: center;
}

    .accepted{
        border:none;
        display:inline;
    }
.unaccepted{
    display:none;
}
```